# Windows tool to split/join large files into 4gb chunks to get around FAT32 limitations

Tags: windows, file-management

I've just noticed that a file I downloaded and can't copy onto my MicroSD card is not due to lack of space on the card, but due to the fact the file is a bit larger than 4GB.

I don't want to change the filesystem on the card to extFAT because I doubt that all of my devices including cameras will work with that fs.

Is there a tool designed to chunk files into 4 gig pieces to work around this very problem?

Comment: If you're prepared to install `Cygwin`, you could use `split`.

Comment: True but I'm looking for a simple-to-install / simple-to-use tool. Work won't like it if I install Cygwin though they don't mind me downloading stuff at work to take home on a USB/SD.

Comment: Understood.   Hope you get a solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use 7-zip, WinRAR or WinZIP to create a non-compressed file.
This is very fast and universal solution, you can open a zip file on any platform later.

[image: 7-zip]

Comment: Sorry, it's not quite clear "a file" - do you mean "a series of files"?

Comment: @hippietrail what Michal describes will split the file into multiple parts, i.e. make create multi-volume zip (`file.z01`, `file.z01` etc.) In the marked box you can define the maximum size each "volume" shall have.

Answer (score 3):

It is a very old tool, but it was designed to solve exactly this problem. [Splitter-Light](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/splitter/splitter.html) is a portable app (only 55KB), what means that you can run it without installation from the sd card.